# dependencies with create-react-native-app

Tags: react-native, dependencies, create-react-native-app

I'm getting a new list of errors as follows:

```
npm ERR! peer dep missing: react@16.3.1, required by react-native@0.55.4
npm ERR! extraneous: websql@0.4.4 d:\atestbed\native-react\lecture4-contacts\node_modules\websql
npm ERR! missing: websql@https://github.com/expo/node-websql/archive/18.0.0.tar.gz, required by expo@27.0.1
npm ERR! peer dep missing: react-native@^0.51 || ^0.52 || ^0.53 || ^0.54, required by react-native-maps@0.21.0
npm ERR! peer dep missing: eslint@^3.17.0 || ^4.0.0, required by eslint-plugin-react-native@3.2.1
```

When I try to install these dependencies I seem to be making the problem worse.  Is this something that will take care of itself with later updates or do I need to solve these issues now?  Any guidance greatly appreciated

UPDATE:

I removed yarn and create-react-native-app and reinstalled, again with -g option.  I then update react to 16.3.1 but got about 50 missing file warnings.  I updated to 16.3.2 but that doesn't work with expo.  Reinstalled react.16.3.1 and now have fewer missing files.

I then install the missing packages but npm ls stills says they are missing:

```
npm ERR! peer dep missing: react-native@^0.51 || ^0.52 || ^0.53 || ^0.54, 
required by react-native-maps@0.21.0
npm ERR! missing: mkdirp@0.5.1, required by node-pre-gyp@0.10.0
npm ERR! missing: minimist@0.0.8, required by mkdirp@0.5.1
npm ERR! missing: safe-buffer@5.1.1, required by readable-stream@2.3.6
npm ERR! missing: safe-buffer@5.1.1, required by string_decoder@1.1.1
npm ERR! missing: string-width@1.0.2, required by gauge@2.7.4
npm ERR! missing: strip-ansi@3.0.1, required by gauge@2.7.4
npm ERR! missing: strip-ansi@3.0.1, required by string-width@1.0.2
npm ERR! missing: ansi-regex@2.1.1, required by strip-ansi@3.0.1
npm ERR! missing: string-width@1.0.2, required by wide-align@1.1.2
npm ERR! missing: once@1.4.0, required by glob@7.1.2
npm ERR! missing: once@1.4.0, required by inflight@1.0.6
npm ERR! missing: wrappy@1.0.2, required by inflight@1.0.6
npm ERR! missing: wrappy@1.0.2, required by once@1.4.0
npm ERR! missing: minipass@2.2.4, required by tar@4.4.1
npm ERR! missing: mkdirp@0.5.1, required by tar@4.4.1
npm ERR! missing: safe-buffer@5.1.1, required by tar@4.4.1
npm ERR! missing: yallist@3.0.2, required by tar@4.4.1
npm ERR! missing: minipass@2.2.4, required by fs-minipass@1.2.5
npm ERR! missing: safe-buffer@5.1.1, required by minipass@2.2.4
npm ERR! missing: yallist@3.0.2, required by minipass@2.2.4
npm ERR! missing: minipass@2.2.4, required by minizlib@1.1.0
```

Comment: Did you tried to remove node_modules ans lock files and then running npm install again?

Comment: this was a complete clean install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's what seems to work:

1. Uninstall yarn (this may not be necessary)
2. roll back npm to version 4.6.1
3. install eslint@4.0.0
4. install ajv@6.0.0
5. add the installs to json file to silence extraneous warning

now the only error you should be left with is:

```
npm ERR! peer dep missing: react-native@^0.51 || ^0.52 || ^0.53 || ^0.54, required by react-native-maps@0.21.0
```

which is a problem with the react-native-maps package used for working with maps not the js function map

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the version that gets installed does not match the version required by react-native.

I fixed this by removing `yarn.lock` and `node_modules` and running `yarn` again to reinstall deps.

I am not sure what is causing the issue, `package.json` has the correct version listed in the dependencies, however the one installed I believe is the latest (possible `yarn.lock` issue? not sure...)

I think this issue in their repo is related: https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/issues/649